# Channel Entry in One Variable?

Tags: variable

Since I need bits and pieces of a channel entry on various parts of my page, is it possible to store the channel entry in one big variable that contains everything? That way, I can access it throughout the template (and embedded templates)?

I've used Stash for variables, usually for one field value only. Now I want the entire channel entry - all the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Stash for this as well. Just create a variable for each value from the channel entry that you want to use.

It seems like you want a less manual process, but there isn't a default EE way of doing that. You probably could build a third party add-on to do something like this, but there aren't any that I know of that have this functionality.

Comment: The "each value from the channel entry" is the approach I want to avoid. Tough.

Comment: You don't have to do it for each custom field. Just set a stash variable that has all the custom fields and html in one chunk (wrap it all with stash:set).

Comment: No, I don't want mark up. I want to be able to access the individual pieces of information so I can use it throughout the page.

Comment: In that case, go with Trevor's suggestion. Or as others have mentioned elsewhere, Global Variables (or Low Variables or Republic Variables) are a good way to handle this scenario instead of a Channel entry.

Comment: You could probably build a custom add-on that loads the channel module and then work in the functionality that you need, but I don't know if that is worth the time it would take.